# Debugging an openTBS error: TinyButStrong Error Show() Method: The output is cancelled by the OpenTBS plugin because at least one error has occured

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I am using openTBS to create dynamic word documents from PHP merging in several variables. The PHP program creates the Word document using the template for whatever language the user selects. This is working fine for other document templates in all languages but I have one template, in Chinese, that gives an error that i have narrowed down to one section but cannot seem to find what the issue is. If i leave that section of the word document out, it works fine. With debugging on it gives the message

```
<br /><b>TinyButStrong Error</b> in field &#91;var.</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:eastAsia...: the key '&lt;/w:t&gt;&lt;/w:r&gt;&lt;w:r&gt;&lt;w:rPr&gt;&lt;w:rFonts w:eastAsia' does not exist or is not set in VarRef. (VarRef seems refers to $GLOBALS) <em>
```

This message can be cancelled using parameter 'noerr'.
". Can anybody help me narrow down how to find this error? Again, the same PHP file works for other language templates so i don't have a problem with the php side and i am able to generate dynamic word documents in Chinese for other templates so I know it is just something in this particular section of this document but cannot find it from the error message. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Is your [var] fields embedded in another TBS field ?

Comment: The section has a [onload;block=tbs:section;when [var.anf]=0] command in it and within the section there are multiple rows in a table of about 25 rows that have commands like this: [onshow.agata186li1] [onload;block=tbs:row;when [var.agfata186li1]=0] and this: [onshow.apata186li1] but all of those are exactly copied from the same template in other languages. It is working in all languages except Chinese.

Comment: it is not a problem with any of the opentbs tags i don't think because I can take them completely out of the section and the document will still give the error. But if i delete the section the document will generate. I just can't figure out how to find the what the problem is from the debugging and from the error message.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite probable that some Chinese characters converted to UTF8 has a ';', and that such characters have broken some parent TBS fields in which they where embedded.

Since you're using embedded fields such as `[onload;block=tbs:section;when [var.anf]=0]` you must be sure that embedded field's value won't break the parent field with spacial characters such as `;` or `'`.

This is because sometime the parent fields are globally evaluated, not only parameter by parameter.

So if your embedded value `[var.anf]` may contain ';' (like special UTF8 character may have), you should protect them like this :

```
[onload;block=tbs:section;when '0'='[var.anf]']
```

Another point is that the TBS error message shows that the field [var.something] is saved with invisible extra XML make-up (`</w:t></w:r>...`).
OpenTBS tries to clean up those extra, but sometimes it cannot do it.
You can clean up those extra XML make-up by select them, cut and then paste-without-formating. Another solution is to use the *OpenTBS add-in for Microsoft Word* provided int the OpenTBS package.

Comment: hi, it doesnt seem to be an issue with my embedded fields. The document template is in Chinese and i mainly use the onload tags to display or not display parts of the document and onshow fields to merge in data from the SQL database, mostly numeric. The document has about 20 sections and all are doing fine except one section. I can take that section out and everything is fine. But if that section is included, even if i take out all of the onshow and onload tags out of the section, it will error out.

Comment: in Firefox the web console says " The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. " in Chrome, it gives a 500 error.

Comment: In my PHP i have: 
$TBS->LoadTemplate($template, OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8); 
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_EDIT_ENTITY, 'word/settings.xml', 'w:settings/w:updateFields', 'w:val', 'true', true);

Comment: The data that i merge in from the php variables is not in Chinese, they are always numbers or text in US english.

Comment: The same php program works fine for English, German, French, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese, Arabic, and Russian. It is not working for Chinese or Japanese, however, I can omit that section of the Chinese template and the rest of it appears to work fine. I havent got that far trying to figure out whats wrong with the Japanese version yet.

Comment: I have several other templates in Chinese and Japanese (albeit they are shorter documents with fewer merge fields and process much quicker) that are working fine.

Comment: Sorry for the extensive essay above but appreciate any advice you can give.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to send something that reproduces the problem ? So I could explore what is going wrong. If the sensitive data comes from a database, you can convert it to php using var_export(). And you can delete all unnecessary parts in the template that does not influences the bug.

Comment: Skrol29, just fixed. I'm so sorry, it was just exceeding max execution time in php. I was looking at php settings and it was showing 0 which i thought meant no timeout but found another php.ini that had 30 and just increased that and both Chinese and Japanese are working fine now. I feel relieved yet dumb.